# What is `modifiedfee` in mempool dump, how is it related to actual fee?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, mempool

In mempool dump through `getrawmempool true`, I see something called `modifiedfee`.

It seems to be the same in all cases (just by looking at the dump). What exactly is it, how does it relate to `fee` (that is also present)?

The help says

> (numeric) transaction fee with fee deltas used for mining priority

but that is not very helpful; that just seems like normal fee.

edit: I went trough the file by iterating over the dump, and modifiedfee and fee are indeed the same on all the transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the `prioritisetransaction` RPC, which changes what fee a transaction has for the purpose of inclusion in blocks.

If you never use `prioritisetransaction`, the modified fee will always be equal to the real fee.

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought it relates to either RBF or CPFP! :)